# using sed how to put space after numbers in a big string

Tags: bash, sed, awk

This question was asked in an interview. I could not answer! So getting some help here to understand the logic. i.e. how to put space between a number string and character string.

Given the string "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" what command you use to get following result -

"1 abc 2 abcd 3 efghi 10 z 11 jkl 100 pqrs"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another -- yet simple -- way to think about it:

```
echo "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" | \
 sed -r 's/([0-9])([a-zA-Z])/\1 \2/g; s/([a-zA-Z])([0-9])/\1 \2/g'
```

- add a whitespace between a digit-letter string & letter-digit string
- `()` is to capture the group and `\1` and `\2` is to return the first and second captured group

Answer (score 4):

With `GNU sed`:

```
$ echo "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" | sed -e 's/[0-9]\+/ & /g' -e 's/^ \| $//'
1 abc 2 abcd 3 efghi 10 z 11 jkl 100 pqrs
```

With `awk`:

```
$ echo "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" | awk '{gsub(/[0-9]+/," & ",$0); $1=$1}1'
1 abc 2 abcd 3 efghi 10 z 11 jkl 100 pqrs
```

- `gsub` with substitute all numbers with space before and after it.
- `$1=$1` will re-compute entire line and add `OFS` (by default single
  space)

Comment: @user1149518 Added an `awk` solution as well.

Comment: The `awk` solution worked on macOS, although none of the `sed` ones did.

Answer (score 3):

I would have chosen [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) over [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
echo "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" | sed 's/[0-9]\+/ & /g; s/^[ ]//; s/[ ]$//'
```

It surrounds each run of digits with spaces and afterwards removes the (possibly) leading and trailing ones.

It yields:

```
1 abc 2 abcd 3 efghi 10 z 11 jkl 100 pqrs
```

Comment: Now you are 20K, zorionak! If I remember properly, I also upvoted to your 10K :)

Comment: @fedorqui: Muchas gracias fedorqui!! It was hard to reach this number, and I struggled a little bit at the end :-) but those upvotes helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo 1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs | \
    sed -r -e 's/([[:digit:]]+)/ \1 /g' -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g'
```

Take the expression `-e 's/([[:digit:]]+)/ \1 /g'` first.

The parentheses around `[[:digit:]]+` 'capture' each sequence of one or more digits. Since it's the first capture group, it's referenced in the substitution by `\1` (then there's the space before and after:  `\1` ).

The `g` tells `sed` to perform this substitution 'globally' on the input.

The `-r` before the expression tells `sed` to use extended regular expressions.

The other two 'expressions' (each expression has `-e` before it to show that it's an expression):
`-e 's/^ *//g'` will remove leading whitespace, and `-e 's/ *$//g'` will remove trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
echo 1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs | perl -F'(\d+)' -ane \
    '$F[0] and print "@F\n" or print "@F[1..$#F]"'
```

Some explanation:

- `-an` together tells Perl to split each line of input and put the resulting fields into the array `@F`.
- `-F` specifies a delimiter of one or more digits to use with `-an` to split the input. The parentheses cause the delimiters themselves to be stored in the array, not just the strings they separate.
- `-e` specifies the code to run after each line is read. We simply want to print the contents of `@F`, with the default field separator (space) used to separate elements of the array. The `and...or` combination is used to ignore the first field if it is empty, as it will be if the input line starts with a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks to ALL. I think this is kind of optimum which I derived from all your answers!    $ echo "1abc2abcd3efghi10z11jkl100pqrs" | sed 's/[a-z]\+/ & /g'
1 abc 2 abcd 3 efghi 10 z 11 jkl 100 pqrs